# JPQL multiple JOIN query

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, hql, jpql

Can someone help me?
I got that SQL query and need to represent that in JPQL, but i faced trouble with right join:

```
SELECT alrt.* 
FROM 
 REACTION.ALERT alrt, REACTION.INVESTIGATION inv, 
 REACTION.CLASSIFICATION_TYPE clst, REACTION.FRAUD_TYPE frt, 
 REACTION.TRANS trns, REACTION.CARD crd  
WHERE
  alrt.ISS_INST IN(1201, 1101) AND 
  alrt.MODULE_TYPE = 0 AND 
  0 < (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM REACTION.INVESTIGATION WHERE REACTION.INVESTIGATION.ALERT_ID = alrt.ID) AND 
  inv.CLASSIFICATION_TYPE_ID IS NOT NULL AND 
  clst.CLASSIFICATION_TYPE = 10 AND 
  (alrt.REMINDER_USER_LOGIN = 'qwr' OR alrt.REMINDER_USER_LOGIN IS NULL) AND 
  alrt.ID = inv.ALERT_ID AND 
  alrt.TRANSACTION_ID = trns.ID(+) AND inv.CLASSIFICATION_TYPE_ID = 
  clst.ID AND inv.FRAUD_TYPE_ID = frt.ID(+) AND trns.HPAN = crd.HPAN(+);
```

After read tutorials and docs i create that JPQL query:

```
SELECT alrt
    FROM INVESTIGATION inv
        JOIN inv.CLASSIFICATION_TYPE_ID clst
        RIGHT JOIN inv.FRAUD_TYPE_ID frt
        JOIN inv.alert_id alrt
        RIGHT JOIN alrt.transactio_id trns
        RIGHT JOIN trns.HPAN crd
    WHERE
        alrt.ISS_INST IN(1201, 1101) AND
        alrt.MODULE_TYPE = 0 AND 0 < (SELECT COUNT(inv1) FROM INVESTIGATION inv1 WHERE  inv1.ALERT_ID = alrt.ID) AND
        inv.CLASSIFICATION_TYPE_ID IS NOT NULL AND
        clst.CLASSIFICATION_TYPE = 2 AND
       (alrt.REMINDER_USER_LOGIN =  'qwr' OR alrt.REMINDER_USER_LOGIN IS NULL);
```

But i got error then try to execute that. Can someone tell what i did wrong pls?
If it make sense i use JPA 1.0 version

Comment: Can you post the error you got?

Comment: ok, i will add error text for an hour, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is join ID, but not OR-mapping object.
Try this:

```
JOIN inv.CLASSIFICATIONTYPE(your mapping property name) clst
```

If u do not have mapping relationship between entities, u'd better to user join table i.o. OR-mapping.
Read more information on [JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_Joins)